# How to count words using within a element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Total number of words will display in the top of Textarea., when i enter or paste some words.

Actually, I gotta total number of words, when i used the element `<textarea id="text"></text>`.

But i can not get the total number of word using `<div id="text"></div>`

Is it possible to count all the words within a element `<div id="text"></div>`?

JS for counting words.

```
counter = function() {
    var value = $('#text').val();

    if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCount').html(0);        
        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);    
};

$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#text').change(counter);
    $('#text').keydown(counter);
    $('#text').keypress(counter);
    $('#text').keyup(counter);
    $('#text').blur(counter);
    $('#text').focus(counter);
});
```

Could someone help me to solve this?

Comment: `var value = $('#text').text();` have you tried it?

Comment: As an aside, you can _heavily_ optimize what's in your domReady statement. Replace all these with `$(document).on('change keydown keypress keyup blur focus', '#text', counter)`. Currently you repeat 6 DOM accesses in a row, that's a terrible design. At least you want to store `$('#text')` in a variable, instead of querying the DOM 6 times : `$text = $('#text')`, and reuse $text.

Comment: Why are you doing `.replace(regex, ' ').split(' ')` instead of `.split(regex)`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because `val()` will retrieve the value of a `textarea` without a problem, however a `div` does not have a `value` property.

For this to work with `div` elements, you should change `val()` to `text()`:

```
var value = $('#text').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text` instead of `val`:

```
var value = $.trim($('#text').text());
```

`val` will give you the `value` attribute value. Whereas `text` will give you the `innerText` of the element(`div`).

**Optimization**

```
var counter = function () {
    var value = $.trim($(this).text()); // Trim spaces

    if (value.length === 0) {
        $('#wordCount').text(0);
        return;
    }

    var wordCount = value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;
    $('#wordCount').text(wordCount);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text').on('change keydown keypress keyup blur focus', counter);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for giving different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this:

```
counter = function() {
    var value = $('#text').text(); //<----change .val() to .text()

    if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCount').html(0);        
        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);    
};

$(document).ready(function() {    
    counter(); //<---call the function here.
});
```

---

You need to call the function on dom ready because all the events you bound on the div needs some event to be happend by the user.